# What is causing Chrome to render gaps between borders?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

In Chrome there are red lines (from the background colour) between the borders which aren't there in firefox.

[Chrome vs Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjkhr.jpg)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: red;
  color: #ccc;
  font-family: Roboto, Garuda;
  border: 12px solid seagreen;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 8px solid mediumpurple;
}

header #logo {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 8px solid gold;
}

header nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 8px solid mediumspringgreen;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 8px solid greenyellow;
}

main article {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 8px solid salmon;
}

main aside {
  border: 8px solid violet;
}

footer {
  border: 8px solid hotpink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">Header</div>
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph text <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr>.</p>
  </article>
  <aside>Sidebar</aside>
</main>
<footer>Footer
</footer>
```

I thought this css would prevent that from happening:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I haven't found an explanation why these gaps are rendered and I suspect I haven't searched for the right keywords. Do you know why this happens in chromium-based browsers or what a solution is?

**UPDATE:**
On Chrome in Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 it's showing the gaps between the borders, but Chrome on Fedora 36 isn't. All browser versions are 103.0.5060.114, don't have extensions enabled and are at 100% zoom. What would be something I could test for to find out what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Your code does not render red lines on my Chrome. Are you sure that you're not using some kind of extension that modifies it?

Comment: I can replicate the lines on Chrome when I'm zoomed in a fractional amount, are you sure you're not zoomed in?

Comment: Weird. All extensions are disabled and 100% zoom.

Comment: It's really strange. On Chrome in Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 it's showing the gaps between the borders, but Chrome on Fedora 36 isn't. All browser versions are 103.0.5060.114, don't have extensions enabled and are at 100% zoom. What would be something I could test for to find out what could cause this behaviour?